# Listings on multiple pages - keep number like Continuedfloat

Tags: listings

I have the following code:

```
{
    \lstset{language=C,
            basicstyle=\tiny,
            tabsize=3,
            frame=lines,
            breaklines=true,
            breakatwhitespace=true}

    \lstinputlisting[float,caption={Caption1},label=txt:Netlink,lastline=69]{file.c}
}

{
    \lstset{language=C,
            basicstyle=\tiny,
            tabsize=3,
            frame=lines,
            breaklines=true,
            breakatwhitespace=true}
\ContinuedFloat
    \lstinputlisting[float,caption={Caption 1 (cont.)},label=txt:Netlink,firstline=71]{code.c}
}
```

It produces something like:

```
        Listing 1.1: Caption 1
The code 

        Listing 1.2: Caption 1 (cont.)
The code
```

I want it to be like if you use \Continuedfloat

```
        Listing 1.1: Caption 1
The code 

        Listing 1.1: Caption 1 (cont.)
The code
```

And then on list of listings I would like it to be shown just once.

I have no idea on how to do it. Any help is more than welcome.

Edit 1: (for @GonzaloMedina)

This is the result including \lstlistoflistings [image: output]

Would it be possible to have only one entry there?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defined two commands `\savecount` and `\contcap`. After the first part of the code, invoke `\savecont` (this simply stores the current value of the `lstlisting` counter). For the continued parts, inside a group invoke `\contcap` (this produces the appropriate counter value and uses a special caption format to produce the desired "(Cont.)" text):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,caption}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{cont}{#1~(cont.)#2#3 }

\newcounter{tmp}

\newcommand\savecount{\setcounter{tmp}{\value{lstlisting}}}
\newcommand\contcap{%
\setcounter{lstlisting}{\value{tmp}}
\addtocounter{lstlisting}{-1}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=cont}}

 \lstset{language=C,
            basicstyle=\tiny,
            tabsize=3,
            frame=lines,
            breaklines=true,
            breakatwhitespace=true
}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\lstinputlisting[float,caption={the first part of a listing},label=txta:Netlink,lastline=2]{code.c}
\savecount

\begingroup
\contcap
\lstinputlisting[float,nolol,caption={the second part of a listing},label=txtb:Netlink,firstline=3,lastline=5]{code.c}
\endgroup

\begingroup
\contcap
\lstinputlisting[float,nolol,caption={the third part of a listing},label=txtc:Netlink,firstline=6]{code.c}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

To prevent multiple entries in an eventual List of listings, use the `nolol` key for the continuations.

Comment: Main problem is that your solution repeats the entry many times when \lstlistoflistings (see edit 1 in the question)

Comment: @jlanza that's no problem, use the `nolol` key in the continuations. See my updated answer.

Comment: and the issue of only having 1 and not listing 1 in the list of listings? Do you know why is that?

Comment: @jlanza that's the default behaviour. If you want to add the word "Listing" in the list, you'll need to add something like `\makeatletter
\def\l@lstlisting#1#2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{1em}{\lstlistingname~#1}{#2}}
\makeatother` (perhaps adjusting the lengths according to your needs) to the preamble.